# CNAME, & Amazon S3 bucket as subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, bucket, cname

I have a S3 bucket called download.mydomain.com

My DNS is managed by a local host and they have set up a CNAME to map download.mydomain.com to s3.amazonaws.com. In so doing, this works perfectly:

http://download.mydomain.com/myimage.jpg

I am working on moving my hosting and having trouble getting this to work right with a new DNS provider. Using a different domain for testing purposes, I have a bucket called square.somedomain.com

I set up a CNAME to map square.somedomain.com to s3.amazonaws.com and then try the url:

http://square.somedomain.com/square.jpg

It finds the image, but then the URL in the browser is changed to:

http://square.somedomain.com.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/square.jpg

How can I prevent this? On my working main domain it does not refresh with the extra "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com" in the browser address bar.

Comment: Did you enable static site hosting on the S3 bucket?

Comment: No. None of my other buckets have this enabled and they are all working fine. I am only hosting images and other binary files, not a website.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Static Website Hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html). It will maintain the URL for your website.

When configuring the `CNAME` record, use the URL provided in the console (eg `www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`) rather than the normal S3 URL (eg `www.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com`).

Comment: I am not sure that will work for a subdomain. My main site will not be at Amazon, as I only want an S3 subdomain.